# JObject.Load Exception

Tags: c#

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(tplFile, Encoding.GetEncoding("GB2312")))
{
    {
        new JsonSerializer();
        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader);
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        ...
```

This is the code of my project.
When JObject.Load function is called, the exception is occurred like as follows.

**"Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1."**

My JSon file is as follows.

```
{
    "general":
    {
        "arryname" : "name1",
        "value" : {
            "size" : "10",
            "format" : "L100",
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: your json object has two extra commas(',') in your JSon file which is causing exception

Answer (score 0):

Your Json file contains error so you are getting exception. This should be the correct json file.You file has extra commas which is causing exception and exception is self-explanatory .

```
[
  {
    "general": {
      "arryname": "name1",
      "value": {
        "size": "10",
        "format": "L100"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try with it, but still error is occurred.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "general": {
    "arryname": "name1",
        "value": {
            "size": "10",
            "format": "L100"
        }
    }
}
```

This is JSon File that I changed.